# how to avoid flickering while changing the controls in the panel very often?

Tags: c#-2.0

i often change the controls in the panel while doing this flickering occurs how to avoid 
this.

i have ten usercontrols,before placin a control i will clear the contents of the panel and
add a newone to the panel.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the controls"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flickering is caused by all of the screen refreshes that occur as you change your controls.

An option would be to have two panels, one live and visible and the other invisible. Add or remove controls on the hidden panel and then swap them when the changes are complete.

There is another way to prevent the refreshes from happening, but unfortunately I'm away from my coding machine and can't give an examp[le at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

The *another way* mentioned by ChrisBD would be a

```
myPanel.SuspendLayout()
//adding and removing all UserControls
//...
myPanel.ResumeLayout(false)
```